# Seminar Notes Repository

Tags: soft-question, gm.general-mathematics

On Seminars, people actually talk a lot more about motivations than when they write in paper. It would be a good idea if there is an online repository where people can upload notes (handwritten, TeXed, or just slides from speaker) from seminars, so that people can share.

A good way to arrange them maybe is by seminar speaker. So overlaps can also be easily detected.

Of course, nowadays there are already a lot of video lectures online. But apparently that's only in some top institutes, and mostly often incomplete.

So I guess my QUESTION is: Do you think it is technically possible? Especially if any website with similar idea exist?...

Comment: Often, you can find slides online on either the author's or the conference's web page.

Comment: See also: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/68442/what-could-be-some-potentially-useful-mathematical-databases/68522#68522

Comment: Voted to close as not a real question. Surely it is *technically* possible. And the second part depends on how one interprets 'similar'. If you would like to discuss this idea http://publishing.mathforge.org/ seems like a much better venue.  