# "Family Tree" of Theorems

Tags: soft-question, reverse-math

Is anyone aware of any attempt to describe the dependencies of theorems (perhaps in mathematics generally, perhaps in some limited areas) in the form of a "family tree"?  That is, each node on the tree might correspond to a theorem, and branches would indicate dependencies between theorems?  I realize that this would not constitute an actual tree -- as there can exist loops -- but this sort of meta-description of theorems might provide some insight not available in other manners.

[Added:] Except in some very formalized proof systems, making the  notion of dependency precise is probably difficult, if not impossible.  But colloquially, people will often make statements such as "Theorem A is used / can be used to prove Theorem B".  I'm sure everyone here can think of many such statements to which few will object.  For those cases, it might be very nice to have some accessible database with this information.  Not only might the data in this "graph" be practically useful (e.g., I want to write an expository paper about five interesting consequences of the Borsuk-Ulam theorem), but perhaps even some "meta-data" might provide valuable insight.  Just a thought.

Comment: directed acyclic graph, hopefully

Comment: Would you like it to include a single theorem depending on several others in addition to simple $A\implies B$ branches?

Comment: Hmm, this is an interesting question -- I didn't think so much about the specifics.  This question came to mind because I am thinking about a specific theorem, and was wondering whether it is built on another specific theorem.  Of course I can track down and read the original paper, but it would be great if this sort of graph were available, and I could just "look it up".

Comment: These dependencies are not unambiguous.  There may be many different proofs of theorem $A$, some of which use theorem $B$, while others use theorem $C$, and still others prove $A$ first and derive $B$ and $C$ as corollaries.

Comment: And yes, I agree, directed.  And hopefully acyclic :)

Comment: You could get a well-defined graph describing the relationships between the results in a particular (traditional) exposition (i.e., textbook).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "dependencies", and why cycles should be forbidden.  You can prove Zorn's lemma Z from Hausdorff's maximality principle H; but H is an immediate consequence of the Teichmüller-Tukey lemma, which itself easily follows from Z.

Comment: @Goldstern but if you read in a textbook "Theorem H. Proof: follows from Z □" then "Theorem Z. Proof: follows from H □", you would throw the book in garbage.

Comment: @YoavKallus Yes, but "Theorem H. Proof: follows from Z" and "Exercise: Show that Z immediately follows from H" is fine.  Lazar asked for 'statements such as "Theorem A is used / can be used to prove Theorem B"'.

Comment: @Goldstern Fair. I would argue that in your particular example you cannot "use H to prove Z" since H "depends" on Z, but then we'll descend to an argument about terms.

Comment: I see how this can become very tricky very quickly, and this is related to what Goldstern and Yoav are discussing -- of course we might have a proof that Theorem A implies Theorem B.  That statement, which we might call Theorem C, does not actually depend on either Theorem A or B.  So I guess that in some sense even edges might be nodes?  This will be messy...

Comment: A family tree for the definitions in a mathematical theory might also be a good idea that maybe is easier to realize.

Comment: A question which seems to be related to this one has been posted recently: [Is there a database for tracking the dependencies of mathematical theorems?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/249383/is-there-a-database-for-tracking-the-dependencies-of-mathematical-theorems)

Answer (score 12):

The idea of "dependencies" is somewhat ill-defined. The [Reverse Mathematics Program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics) has one way of defining dependencies by comparing the theorems over a very weak base theory called RCA<sub>0</sub>. To see nice diagrams stemming from this program, check out the [Reverse Mathematics Zoo](http://rmzoo.math.uconn.edu/)!

Comment: What does a double-headed arrow mean in one of these diagrams (e.g. http://rmzoo.math.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/841/2014/09/diagram_i.pdf)? I think what Menachem is asking about is dependencies -- i.e. what statements are used to prove what statements -- not implications. While the question of implications is also fascinating, I think it is orthogonal to the question Menachem was asking.

Comment: @YoavKallus: Double arrows usually mean that the converse implication is known to be false. Dependency is very hard to define rigorously. The connection is that if $A$ really depends on $B$ then it must be that $B$ implies $A$. Otherwise, we could use something strictly weaker than $A$ to prove $B$. (For example, $A \lor B$ could be used instead of $A$.) There doesn't seem to be any other purely mathematical ways of defining "dependency". There are, of course, historical and sociological ways to define dependency that behave differently.

Comment: Just to clarify, I think the double arrows your are talking about are the *double stroked* arrows, not the *double headed* arrows.

Comment: @YoavKallus Sorry, I misread your description of the arrows. I guess you mean the equivalences rather than the strict implications.

Answer (score 5):

Concerning (parts of) algebraic geometry, the [Stacks Project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu) offers so-called dependency graphs.

Comment: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01F2/graph/force  is a link for the graph for the Leray spectral sequence.

Answer (score 3):

### Formal vs self-organised knowledge systems: a network approach

A.P. Masucci, [Physica A 390 (2011) 4652-4659](http://arxiv.org/ct?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdx.doi.org%2F10%252E1016%2Fj%252Ephysa%252E2011%252E06%252E074&v=0c54bcc5) ([arXiv:1105.1058](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.1058))

> In this work we consider the topological analysis of symbolic formal systems in the framework of network theory. In particular we analyse the network extracted by Principia Mathematica of B. Russell and A.N. Whitehead, where the vertices are the statements and two statements are connected with a directed link if one statement is used to demonstrate the other one. We compare the obtained network with other directed acyclic graphs, such as a scientific citation network and a stochastic model. We also introduce a novel topological ordering for directed acyclic graphs and we discuss its properties in respect to the classical one. The main result is the observation that formal systems of knowledge topologically behave similarly to self-organised systems.

This paper looks at how logical statements such as theorems are organized in specific expository works (like the *Principia*). As others have noted in the comments, outside such organized works, the dependencies can be ambiguous as theorems can have alternate proofs. Moreover, the order of deriving theorems is not canonical so that if all proof paths were included, cycles will have formed. The *Principia* is as good as any work to start with, but I would really love to see a similar analysis on Bourbaki and on Euclid's Elements.

[image: Figure 3 of Mascuni 2011]
Figure from the paper: distribution of in and out degrees in the Principia DAG, in the DAG of citations, and in a stochastic generative model.

Answer (score 2):

There are fairly recent dependency graphs relating to Euclid's Book 1, Elements, in the literature.
See A Boxer's paper in Bridges Art/Math 2015
Also see M. Schiefsky (Harvard Classics) and Boman (Penn State Math) and Nyugen (Berkeley) for overviews and graphs.
The most interesting is that of Jesse Atkinson, Bridges Art/Math 2016, that shows a 3-D in-tree dependency graph of Euclid's proof of the Pythagorean Theorem (1.47) embedded in a discussion about the overall role of 1.45 and 1.47 in that book.  It is an elegant "little" paper, by an undergraduate math student, to say the least.